# Making a command line application from a C program

Tags: c

How do I convert this program(binary.c) into a command line application so it can read any binary text (e.g. `binary1.txt`) file and then convert it to ASCII? For example I want to do:

```
./binary < binary1.txt
```

and it should print

> Hello World!

at the command line.

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE *f_ptr;
f_ptr = fopen("binary1.txt", "r");
if (f_ptr == NULL){
printf("Error opening binary1.txt");
return 1;
}

while(1){
int ch = fgetc(f_ptr);
if(ch == EOF)
break;

printf("%c",ch);

}

fclose(f_ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show sample of `binary1.txt`.

Comment: Are you asking how to build an executable from source?

Comment: Do you know what `<` actually does in your shell? Do you know how to run your program from the command line? Once you know both those things, hopefully it should be straightforward.

Comment: If you mean to have the program take input from a redirected file rather than a pre-named one, just use stdin/stdout instead of opening files by name.

Comment: 100100011001011101100110110011011110100000101011111011111110010110110011001000100001 this is the binary.txt file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to pass the filename to your program and not sure how to do that. In that case you might want to do this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if(argc>1)
  std::string filename = argv[1];
  //now you have the file in the filename

 // your code 
 return 0;
}
```

so when you execute just do this

```
./binary binary1.txt
```

you don't need to use `<` and I am assuming that both your executable and text file are in the same directory

Comment: The question was about C. This is not C.

Comment: And `if(argc)` should be `if(argc>1)`

Comment: ... and `char argv[]` should be `char *argv[]`... -sighs- Why was this accepted?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. I guess you need to compile your source using a compiler. If you are using Linux you could do:`gcc binary.c -o binary` to get an executable file...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    if(argc < 2)//./binary < binary1.txt
        fp = stdin;
    else {//./binary  binary1.txt
        if((fp=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
            perror("fopen");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int ch, count = 0;
    unsigned char out = 0;
    while((ch = fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        if(ch == '1' || ch == '0'){
            out <<= 1;
            out += ch - '0';
            if(++count == 7){//7bit code
                printf("%c", out);
                count = out = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    puts("");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/VAlwM9)